# Change number of items in RallyGrid

Tags: gridview, grid, rally

Currently, if you add a "rallyGrid" this shows by default a list of 25 items. To show more elements, you have to change the number of items by selecting another value in the drop-down menu and it refreshes automatically.

Is there any way to make it show 50 or more elements by default instead of 25?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can set the `pageSize` property on the Store.  From the example here

https://docs.ca.com/en-us/ca-agile-central/saas/apps/2.1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.grid.Grid

I was able to change it to 25, 50, 100 or 200:

and here is some more information on the Store:

https://docs.ca.com/en-us/ca-agile-central/saas/apps/2.1/doc/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-pageSize

And the example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
     items: [{
         xtype: 'rallygrid',
         columnCfgs: [
             'FormattedID',
             'Name',
             'Owner'
         ],
         storeConfig: {
             model: 'userstory',
             pageSize: 200
         }
     }],
     renderTo: Ext.getBody()
 });
```